# How to bind an ip AND ports to subdomains using JBoss (Or Apache Tomcat)

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss, subdomain

This is my problem:

I have a JBoss server (Running an existing app) and a Apache Tomcat (Running an app created by me) server running on the same server with different ports.

I have two subdomain names which i have routed to the IP of the server.

What i need to do is to bind the subdomain names to the IP, but with different ports.

I saw an easy way to do it with XAMPP and apache, editing the httpd.conf, but i can't find any simular fway to do it with Apache Tomcat or JBoss.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

---

I rather have a solution on the question above, but the question below can be accepted as a backup solution:

Since i could not figure that out, i had to at least have a solution to one of the applications (the one running at JBoss).

So i configured JBoss to port 80 instead of 8080.
What happens now if i go to the subdomains is that i get the JBoss welcome window.
How can i change the default JBoss "app" to my app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get this:

```
sub1.domain.com(192.168.0.1) on port 80 --> jboss app
sub2.domain.com(192.168.0.1) on port 80 --> tomcat app
```

without either adding to or subtracting from your software stack.

Your options are:

- use jboss to run your tomcat app
- add a reverse-proxy
- use an HTTP-aware layer 7 firewall

The first is probably easiest; jboss deploys web applications using tomcat (or, in more recent versions, a fork of tomcat called [jbossweb](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/)), so you can probably just drop your .war into the deploy directory.

If that's not possible for some reason, I'd use a reverse-proxy.  Apache HTTPD with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or [mod_jk](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is fairly common.  If you go the mod_jk route and you have non-trivial load, I'd review [this](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-15866).

The last I'm not familiar with.  I imagine that the spendy Cisco firewalls can do this, and I'm sure it's possible to hack iptables to do it too, but my google-fu failed to find specifics.

Comment: Thanks, i decided to install Xampp (including apache), and will be trying to use ProxyPassReverse